# Error WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the following error when I tried to [import the JS SDK Veriff](https://github.com/Veriff/veriff-js-sdk). How can I resolve this error ?

> TypeError: _veriff_js_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is
> not a function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Veriff from '@veriff/js-sdk';

@Component({
  selector: 'hp',
  templateUrl: './hp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hp.component.css']
})
    export class HPComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const v =  Veriff({
      host:'',
      apiKey:'',
      parentId:'',
      onSession: (err:any, res:any) => {

      }
    });
```

I have also tried adding the following to my tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
     "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
     "strictInjectionParameters": true,
     "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
     "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the import to:

```
import { Veriff } from '@veriff/js-sdk';
```

(taken from the documentation at https://github.com/Veriff/veriff-js-sdk#install-js-sdk)

Comment: If so I get this error "'Veriff' can only be imported by using a default import.ts(2595). I am new to this. Help
"

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with the package's types: https://github.com/Veriff/veriff-js-sdk/issues/40 You can add a // @ts-ignore comment above the import to ignore it.

Comment: How can I add the comment? Sorry, but I am a newbie .

Comment: No worries! Just a line that says `// @ts-ignore` before the line that says `import { Veriff } from '@veriff/js-sdk'`